# How Can I Order The Scores List By Newest Added? Unity C#

Tags: unity, c#, 2d, 3d

I have 5 scripts to make the scoreboard. But I don't know how to order the list (the scores which are stores in a list) by newest added. Can someone please help me? Thanks :)

First Script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Linq;
using TMPro;

public class RowUi : MonoBehaviour
{
    public TextMeshProUGUI score;
}
```

Second Script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Linq;
using System;

public class ScoreManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    private ScoreData sd;

    private void Awake()
    {
        var json = PlayerPrefs.GetString("scores", "{}");
        sd = JsonUtility.FromJson<ScoreData>(json);
    }

    public IEnumerable<Score> GetHighScore()
    {
        // **THIS IS WHERE THE SCORE IS ORDERD BY DESCENDING** //
        return sd.scores.OrderByDescending(x => x.score);
    }

    public void AddScore(Score score)
    {
        sd.scores.Add(score);
    }

    private void OnDestroy()
    {
        SaveScore();
    }

    public void SaveScore()
    {
        var json = JsonUtility.ToJson(sd);
        PlayerPrefs.SetString("scores", json);
    }
}
```

Third Script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Linq;

public class ScoreUi : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static ScoreUi instance;

    public RowUi rowUi;
    public ScoreManager scoreManager;

    private void Start()
    {
        instance = this;

        if(gameObject.activeInHierarchy == true)
        {
            ScoreUi.instance.AddScoreToBoard();
        }

        var scores = scoreManager.GetHighScore().ToArray();
        for(int i = 0; i < scores.Length; i++)
        {
            var row = Instantiate(rowUi, transform).GetComponent<RowUi>();
            row.score.text = scores[i].score.ToString();
        }
    }

    public void AddScoreToBoard()
    {
        scoreManager.AddScore(new Score(UserInput.instance.score));
    }
}
```

Fourth Script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System;

[Serializable]
public class ScoreData
{
    public List<Score> scores;

    public ScoreData()
    {
        scores = new List<Score>();
    }
}
```

Fifth Script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System;

[Serializable]
public class Score
{
    public int score;

    public Score(int score)
    {
        this.score = score;
    }
}
```

I hope I explained this well enough and if you need extra info, just tell me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, we can add a date field to the score type. We'll make it a `long` so it's easy to serialize, but also add a getter to access it as a `DateTime` object for when that's more convenient to read.:

```
[Serializable]
public class Score
{
    public int score;
    public long timestamp;
    public System.DateTime dateAdded { 
        get { 
            return System.DateTime.FromFileTimeUtc(timeStamp);
        }
    }

    public Score(int score)
    {
        this.score = score;
        // Assign our time stamp whenever logging a new score.
        timestamp = System.DateTime.Now.ToFileTimeUtc();
    }
}
```

Then we can order our scores by date the same way we order them by value:

```
public IEnumerable<Score> GetHighScore()
{
    // **THIS IS WHERE THE SCORE IS ORDERED BY DESCENDING** //
    return sd.scores.OrderByDescending(x => x.score);
}


public IEnumerable<Score> GetLatestScore()
{
    // **THIS IS WHERE THE SCORE IS ORDERED FROM NEWEST TO OLDEST** //
    return sd.scores.OrderByDescending(x => x.timeStamp);
}
```

To erase the saved scores, just reset your score data before saving:

```
public void ClearAllSavedScores() {
    // Replace our score data with a new empty list of scores.
    sd = new ScoreData();
    // Save this empty collection to replace what's in PlayerPrefs.
    SaveScore();
}
```

As you can see, all of this is a pretty trivial modification of what you already had, plus use of the [standard `DateTime` type you can find fully explained in the Microsoft .NET documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime?view=net-6.0). If you struggle with this, then you may want to work your way through some more beginner programming tutorials to learn the ins and outs of the language.